# How to create Client-side environment variables in netlify

Tags: gatsby, netlify, contentful

I use netlify to deploy a gatsby app from a git repos, and I use contentful as my CMS. In order to use content delivery api, I have defined accessToken and space id at client-side, now it works fine. But the accessToken is plain text so it’s a security issue to expose the accessToken. I know netlify can create enviroment variables, but it seems the variables only works at Server-side. I have created a variable named **CONENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN**, I can access it use **process.env.CONENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN** at gatsby-config.js, gatesby-node.js and so on, but I can't access it at client-side, so How to do?
this is my client.js, it runs at client-side.

```
const client=contentful.createClient({
  space:'your spaceid',
  accessToken:'your access token',
})
```

how to change to:
const client=contentful.createClient({
space:'your space id',
accessToken:NETLIFY_ENVIROMENT_VARIABLE_NAME,
})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Netlify, you need to prefix with `GATSBY_` all your environment variables. As it is shown in [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/).

> In addition to these Project Environment Variables defined in `.env`.*
> files, you could also define OS Env Vars. OS Env Vars which are
> prefixed with `GATSBY_` will become available in browser JavaScript.

So you `CONENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN` and other variables will become `GATSBY_CONENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN` (and so on). Once they are set locally (to keep cohesion and avoid duplicity), you must change them in your Netlify application (under https://app.netlify.com/sites/YOURSTIE/settings/deploys#environment):

[image]

The same procedure for the `spaceId`.

To use this variables, you need to simply add them in you `gatsby-config.js`:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
  options: {
    spaceId: process.env.GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_SPACEID,
    accessToken: process.env.GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    host: `preview.contentful.com`,
  },
},
```

And:

```
const client=contentful.createClient({
  space:process.env.GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_SPACEID,
  accessToken: process.env.GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
})
```

Reference: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-contentful/

Comment: Thanks , I'm still puzzled, so I should change variable CONENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN to GATSBY_CONENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN in netlify? And use CONENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN at server-side, use GATSBY_CONENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN at client-side? or shoule I create another variable GATSBY_CONENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN in netlify?

Comment: Yes exactly. In Netlify, you *must use* prefixed variables with `GATSBY_` so you need to use `GATSBY_CONENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN`. To keep cohesion I would recommend using everywhere the same variable name so I would recommend prefixing all variables and use `GATSBY_CONENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN` (and the same for others).

Comment: Keep me posted!

Comment: Hi,@Ferran Buireu, It does not work, I create new two varaibles, GATSBY_CONENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN and GATSBY_CONENTFUL_SPACE_ID, and I change  client.js to use these two variable. When netlify deploys, it throws "WebpackError: ReferenceError: GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID is not defined"

Comment: Are you using them? How? I'm afraid you are not using those `.env` variables. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm sure I dont use .env file, I didn't upload this file to git repos, A good news is I have resolved this problem, I change GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID to  ${process.env.GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID}, same for GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN, It works, thank u.